# Interpolate temperature data (shapefile) using R

Tags: raster, shapefile, r, interpolation, elevation

The answer below solved my fist question, so I edit my question as follows:

I have a shapefile given with the attributes **lat**, **lon**, **elevation** and **temperature**.

So far I have a script that interpolates only the temperature data:

```
#read shapefile:    
shape <- readOGR("C:/Users.../Testarea.gdb", "temperature_data")
#grid shapefile:
shape.grid <- spsample(shape, type = "regular", offset = (c1,1))
gridded(shape.grid) <- TRUE

#kriging:
test <- krige(Temperatur~1, shape, shape.grid)
spplot(test[[1]])
```

Now my problem is that I should also need to consider the elevation, since the temperature is often dependant on this parameter. How can I do this?

Comment: With `r` questions it's useful to provide a minimal reproducible example so we can test solutions. Can you edit your question either to include a link to your shapefile, either in its original location or use a file sharing site?

Comment: I'm really curious... Are you attempting this in the R-ArcGIS Bridge, or running in straight R?

Comment: I will upload a shape file tomorrow. I have a R-Arcgis bridge running but first I want to do a stand-alone script and then maybe later edit it to implement the script into arcgis :)

Comment: I uploaded my .gdb with the shapefile to my google drive:
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B6Da7ufcre_Yd2xFVnZYSS1xTlU&usp=sharing

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: @Phil did you get the chance to try a solution to interpolate the data considering the elevation? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't pass `shape.grid` to `krige`. Try:

```
library(gstat)
test = krige(Temperatur ~ 1, shape, shape.grid)
spplot(test[1])
```

Your example does not work as is, `ssample` should have been `spsample`. For your second question, you will need a grid with elevation data.

Comment: Thanks, i edited my sample from ssample to spsamle. Still, your script edit does not give me the kriged data, instead i only get a grid.

I uploaded my gdb in the comments to my original post, maybe you could take a look at it? Thanks for your help!

Comment: use `spplot` instead of `plot`; I edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you!
The spplot works just fine. Now the only trouble is that i did not consider the elevation yet.